# JOIN with ON <column> = <constant> gives "JOIN expression not supported" error

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
String sqlQuery = @"SELECT la.id, ac.id
 FROM lablesM as la LEFT JOIN
 actions as ac
ON ac.id = 4;";
```

this is the error:

```
JOIN expression not supported.
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not a proper join because the ON clause condition has no reference to any lablesM column.

Comment: Are the two tables related at all? If yes: over which columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should rewrite your SQL statement as

```
String sqlQuery = @"SELECT la.id, ac.id
 FROM lablesM as la inner JOIN
 actions as ac
ON (ac.id = la.id)
where ac.id = 4;";
```

I suppose la.id is foreign key field.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this :

```
"SELECT la.id, ac.id
 FROM lablesM la 
 LEFT JOIN actions ac
 ON ac.id = la.id 
 AND ac.id = 4;"
```